# How to override SqsConfiguration to return custom implementation of SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

In our Spring boot application we use Spring Cloud AWS:

- spring-cloud-starter-aws
- spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure
- spring-cloud-aws-messaging

to receive messages from a SQS queue. However we need to be able to start the application even if the queue is not accessible (i.e "*(Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied*"). In order to do that, we need to be able to override the `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration` class, and provide our own implementation of `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer`.

What is the correct way to do this, and not break autowiring in our existing code?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092518/how-to-configure-custom-spring-cloud-aws-simplemessagelistenercontainerfactory-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `@Bean` for the custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory`, but still leave `@EnableSql` and `SqsConfiguration` will be `@Autowired` with your customization.