# How to configure custom Spring Cloud AWS SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory so it keeps working with @SqsListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am trying to get SpringCloud AWS SQS working with a custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` so i can set timeouts and maxnumber of messages. Without the custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` methods that are annotated with the `@SqsListener` nicely pickup messages that are in SQS. But when i try to configure a custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` the annotation stops working.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    factory.setWaitTimeOut(2000);
    return factory;
}
```

How can i get the normal @SqsListener behaviour when defining a custom SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory?

```
@Component
public class SqsMessageConsumer {
    @SqsListener("incoming-data")
    private void doSomething(String payload) {
        System.out.println("data = " + payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what you have missed but there is a test exactly for such a use-case:

```
@EnableSqs
@Configuration
public static class ConfigurationWithCustomContainerFactory {


    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQS());
        ...
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS() {
        return AMAZON_SQS;
    }

}
```

So, `@EnaqbleSqs` is still here and `SqsConfiguration` is `@Autowired` with your custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` `@Bean`.

Comment: I found the problem. The factory.setWaitTimeOut(2000); was the problem. I assumed that the time was in milliseconds.. :) Thanks for helping out!!

Comment: I need to Implement sqslistener using similar approach as you have Implement. I have try to find on internet to get some demo example but I couldn't . can you please help me provide Implementation of your approach. It would be great help for me.